# Xcode; Set height of UIScrollView automatically depending in its content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, scrollview

I'm developing an iOS app with Xcode and Swift.

In one `ViewController` there's a `UIScrollView`. In this `ScrollView` there are multiple `UITextFields` and `UILabels`. But it takes more height that it's fitting on the device screen and I'm not able to scroll down to see the remaining content.

Does anybody know a way to set `UIScrollViews` height automatically depending in its content?

*P.S. Of cause, I already googled, but the codes I found don't work.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decleare outlet like and connect:

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView?
```

Set its content size using `contentSize` method like this:

```
self.scrollView!.contentSize = CGSize(width:1234, height: 5678)
```

**Set Y position of last UI content plus its height too to the `height: 5678` parameter**. So you will be able to see all contents.

set your constraints accordingly see image. [image]

Comment: Hey @vaibhav, I'm having this code now: `override func viewDidLoad() {` `super.viewDidLoad()` `self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:600, height: 800)` `}` But it's still not working. No error message but also not working. Same as before. Any ideas?

Comment: probably you outlet not connected properly ..just check you `scrollview's` outlet is connected to `scrollview` on storyboard

Comment: Yes, it is. Otherwise I would also get an error. Other ideas?

Comment: see my updated code use `!` front of `scrollview` before set contentSize ..this code working perfect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121930/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-david).

Comment: Hi @vaibhav, it's working now. Thank you very much. Setting the constant did the trick for me. No of the code needed, but could be helpful for other peoples. Thanks a lot.